# Idiomatic Scala: Mapping over option depending on condition

Tags: scala

I have two `val`s, a `condition` and an `option`. Note that `condition` is a simple boolean, not depending on the option's value.

If `condition` holds true, I would like to map over the option to convert it to a result value. In all other cases, I would like to return a `defaultResult`.

This works and is quite readable, but I dislike the duplication of `defaultResult`:

```
val result = if (condition) {
  option.map(valueToResult).getOrElse(defaultResult)
} else {
  defaultResult
}
```

My second approach does not have duplications, but I dislike the fact that filter is abused for something that is not actually dependent on the option's value:

```
val result = option.filter(_ => condition).map(valueToResult).getOrElse(defaultResult)
```

What's a more idiomatic or otherwise better approach in Scala?

Comment: Why do you feel the `filter` is abused? Because it's filtering based on an external value which doesn't have to do with the underlying value of the `Option[T]`? There is no rule which states "use `filter` only to filter out properties of the underlying `Option[T]`." I'd go with the second.

Comment: Exactly. I am aware that there's no rule, it's just a personal (dis)taste.

Comment: I see what you mean. I get that feeling too sometimes. See my answer for a possible alternative solution.

Comment: Side comment on poor choice of `Boolean` - https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Option.collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]):

> Returns a `scala.Some` containing the result of applying `pf` to this
>   `scala.Option`'s contained value, if this option is nonempty and `pf` is
>   defined for that value.

```
val result = option.collect {
  case x if condition => valueToResult(x)
}.getOrElse(defaultResult)
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov why not just do `option match {}` instead of `option.collect {}` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Because she wants to apply a filter based on an external condition. That's just one way of doing it.

Comment: `option match` is actually very nice, too. I posted it as an answer just for documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
val result = option match {
  case Some(value) if condition => valueToResult(value)
  case _ => defaultResult
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val result = (for (v<-option if condition) yield valueToResult(v)).getOrElse(defaultResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
option.foldLeft(defaultResult)((d,x) => if (condition) valueToResult(x) else d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = (condition match {
  case true => option.map(valueToResult)
  case false => None
}).getOrElse(defaultResult)
```